# Array not being overwritten

Tags: arrays, perl

This is a loop and the array does not get overwritten, it just grows.

```
   for ( $j=0; $j <=$#just_ecps ; $j++){
   print "$just_ecps[$j]\n";
   for ($x=0; $x<=$#folder_dates ; $x++){
   my $archivo_histo = "/home/ha2_d11/data/ibprod/archive/$folder_dates[$x]/$just_ecps[$j]/ghistogram.gz";
      next unless (-r $archivo_histo);
      open(FILEHANDLE, "gunzip -c $archivo_histo |") or die ("could not open file $archivo_histo");
      while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
         if ($_ =~ /ave:\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s/){
           push ( @ecp_average , $1);
            sleep 1;
         }
      print "@ecp_average\n";
      }
   }
```

In every instance it is the last three values that are valid, everything before it is a duplicate. I need to get rid of the duplicates and just keep the last three values.

```
Eislnd1
0.00420743 0.00414601 0.0044511
Eislnd2
0.00420743 0.00414601 0.0044511 0.00303575 0.00309721 0.00302753
Eislnd3
0.00420743 0.00414601 0.0044511 0.00303575 0.00309721 0.00302753 0.0031753 0.00324729 0.00295381
Eislnd4
0.00420743 0.00414601 0.0044511 0.00303575 0.00309721 0.00302753 0.0031753 0.00324729 0.00295381 0.00324191 0.00344244 0.00311481
```

Comment: Why are you pushing into an array if you don't want to keep all the values?

Comment: Why do you have `sleep 1` in your code?????

Comment: you know what that is a good point - i wanted to use List::Util to add the values and then average them - using the $#array lenght values was a great way to divide the sum and get the average

Comment: i added sleep to see what was going on with the code - as it goes on is justa whole screen of values.

Comment: when i take out the array and just print the $1 it comes out the way I want it - now i just have to figure out how to add the values and then average then

Answer (score 7):

You need to clear the array for every file:

```
open(FILEHANDLE, "gunzip -c $archivo_histo |") or die ...
@ecp_average = ();
while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
 ...
}
```

At some point you'll want to read up on lexically-scoped variables (i.e. the `my` declaration)
but for now this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Things to note that will help improve this code:

- `use strict; use warnings;`
- Consider using `for my $just_ecp ( @just_ecps ) { ... }` instead of the C-style construct
- Defining an averaging subroutine ( `sub avg { sum(@_) / @_ }` ) and using it ( `avg( @ecp )` ) is a more intuitive way to compute averages instead of mucking around with array lengths. All it takes one line!

Comment: yeah i need to migrate away from the arcane c constructs